# How can I change language in Fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I want to change language in Fullcalendar, but it doesn't work.

Here's how I can change language in official document.
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/locale

I used "Loading Locales with Script Tags and Browser Globals" way on this site.

THIS IS PART OF home.html

> 

```
<script type="module" src="node_modules/fullcalendar/locales/ko.js"></script>
<script>

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      locale:"ko",
      initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    });
    calendar.render();
  });

</script
```

And THIS IS WHAT ko.js looks like.

> console.log("trying to change Korean");
>
> FullCalendar.globalLocales.push(function () {   'use strict';
>
> var ko = {
> code: 'ko',
> buttonText: {
> prev: '이전달',
> next: '다음달',
> today: '오늘',
> month: '월',
> week: '주',
> day: '일',
> list: '일정목록',
> },
> weekText: '주',
> allDayText: '종일',
> moreLinkText: '개',
> noEventsText: '일정이 없습니다',   };
>
> return ko;
>
> }());

My website shows calendar but my code doesn't change language in calendar.
In console, there's "trying to change Korean" which I put in ko.js to know whether it is
imported, but still no language change.
Can not understand what is problem..... Thank you...

Comment: Shouldn't `src="node_modules/fullcalendar/locales/ko.js"` actually be `src="fullcalendar/core/locales/ko.js"` (or possibly `src="node_modules/fullcalendar/core/locales/ko.js"`)?

Comment: I don't have file named 'core.' :(

Comment: Oh, then you are probably using an older version of fullcalendar. Have you tried to create the calendar outside of the `DOMContentLoaded` event listener? What happens if you do that?